# MySQL trigger - delete data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, trigger

I would like to delete data in multiple tables, from a trigger but it seem like my syntax is incorrect.

I got the error: "you've got a error in your MySQL syntax please check the manual".

This is the SQL for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_organisation`
BEFORE DELETE ON `organisations`
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE OLD.id = organisation_id ; 
DELETE FROM orders WHERE OLD.id = orders.organisation_id;
DELETE from organisations_products where OLD.id = organisation_id ;
DELETE FROM organisations WHERE OLD.id = organisations.parent ;
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use a foreign key with `on delete cascade`?

Comment: because there are trigger on all those other table , and on delete cascade , do not fire trigger on mysql

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `BEGIN` ... `END`, as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `delete_organisation`
BEFORE DELETE ON `organisations`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM contacts WHERE OLD.id = organisation_id ; 
  DELETE FROM orders WHERE OLD.id = orders.organisation_id;
  DELETE from organisations_products where OLD.id = organisation_id ;
  DELETE FROM organisations WHERE OLD.id = organisations.parent ; 
END $$
```